# Drawing on screen, directly from the gpu

Tags: drawing, cuda, screen, gpu

I am doing some processing/pixel classification on a picture and I'm using a gpu for it. My question is: is there a library that i can use, in order to print my final picture (2d matrix) on screenm directly from the gpu memory instead of bringing it back to  cpu and printing from there?

I don't want anything extravagant, i will only color the pixels and i want to show the new colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenGL](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/documents/1055_GTC09.pdf&ei=9zDkTqjVCK2NigKYnNjOBg&usg=AFQjCNEOCo1un-SOHbxAFYWaI7ocsCthMA), Cuda draws to a texture and openGL tells the card to display it

See the [mandlebrot example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#mandelbrot)

Update: opencl 1.1 now allows sharing opengl contexts with opencl code

Comment: The first link is dead. I have updated the second link (please check if it is correct).